# Regex - Finding all function names that doesn't start with a certain prefix

Tags: regex, grep

I have a folder containing many PHP files that I need to recursively search for function definitions which don't start with `abc`. So I need to get all occurrences of `function something() {` where `abc` is not a prefix of `something`. What is the regex I can use with grep to achieve this?

Comment: the general regex for this would look like this (negative lookahead): `function (?!abc)[^\{]+ \{`

Comment: @MichaelRitter It's not working! :(

Comment: wow... thats very descriptive... "its not working"... Any more details? does it match to many or to few function heads? ...?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it doesn't match any such function definition

Comment: can you give some examples of what it doesn't match? you also may have to alter it so that the space is optional or to also check for start/end of regex. here are some examples i tested: http://regexr.com/3f5at

Comment: Also: it could be that grep doesn't support the full regex spectrum (and from the looks of it you should try to not escape the `{` (or double-escape))

Comment: Your regex seems perfect on the example. But when I run it on the terminal **grep -r 'function (?!bp_)[^\{]+ \{'** I get the error **grep: Unmatched \{**

Comment: @MichaelRitter I like your short regex. It will however also match every lines which has somewhere the word `function` in it. Like a comment `\\ this is a function which is great`. But otherwise +1

Comment: @samurdhilbk try removing the escape-characters from the `{` (the backslash before it). @ssc-hrep3 yea but this way it can match functions that aren't on their own line... its complicated to match everything correctly in this case i think

Comment: it's impossible to match everything correctly with a regexp. Consider text inside comments or strings or ....

Comment: @MichaelRitter Using `grep -P` worked with the regex you mentioned. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this regular expression:

```
(?:\r?\n|^)\s*?function\s(?!abc).*?\{
```

**Here is an example in JavaScript (the demo text is in HTML):**

```js
var text = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
var regex = /(?:\r?\n|^)\s*?(function\s(?!abc).*?\{)/g;
var match = regex.exec(text)

while(match !== null) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  match = regex.exec(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="white-space:pre;">
function abc123 {
     function abc123 {
function something {
function abcsomething {
if {
function 123 {
no-match
</div>
```

Comment: You were right, didn't think about that. I fixed it

Comment: Thanks for this @ssc-hrep3. I tried it myself with JS and it works. But when I use the same with grep it doesn't give me any matches. Does grep use a different regex format?

Comment: Did you use `grep -E` or `egrep` instead of the recursive `grep -r`?

Comment: Using `grep -P` worked! Then `grep` uses Perl regex.